# How many Marvel One-Shots are there, where were they released, and where can they be found?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel-one-shots

Since the (relatively) recent addition to Disney+ of *All Hail the King*, a Marvel "One-Shot", I've been wondering: how many Marvel One-Shots are there? Where were they originally released? Are they still available or have they become ghosts of the past?

I'm looking for:

- A complete list of the One-Shots
- Original release date/movie
- Current place to view (e.g. "Disney+" for *All Hail the King*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of December 13th, 2021, it seems there are [five official MCU "One-Shots"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_One-Shots), available on various bits of home media:

- **The Consultant**,   September 13, 2011, available on *Thor*
- **A Funny Thing Happened on the Way to Thor's Hammer**,   October 25, 2011,   available on *Captain America: The First Avenger*
- **Item 47**,  September 25, 2012, available on *Marvel's The Avengers*
- **Agent Carter**, September 3, 2013 (digital) / September 24, 2013 (physical), available on *Iron Man 3*
- **All Hail the King**,    February 4, 2014 (digital) / February 25, 2014 (physical), available on *Thor: The Dark World*

[This article](https://www.mousehacking.com/blog/complete-guide-to-marvel-on-disney-plus) suggests that only **The Consultant** and **Agent Carter** are on Disney+ as of June, 2021, but as you note, **All Hail the King** is now on there. Unfortunately, I don't have access to my account to verify whether the others have been added.

The *Team Thor* shorts are not officially "One-Shots".

Comment: Isn't there also a spiderman short?

Comment: @ibid: Spider-Man's of perfectly average height.

Comment: https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Peter%27s_To-Do_List

Comment: Ah, much like "Peter Parker Takes His Driving Test", I think that was a Sony release, not a Disney MCU release.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - IIRC, the To-Do list was comprised of material that had been filmed and then cut out of the movie, and they decided to edit it together as a short instead of just posting them as deleted scenes. I'm not familiar with the driving test video, but on watching it it seems like it was just a promotional video.

Comment: Nevertheless, it doesn't look like Disney has it on its One-shot list for all that Sony and Disney are working together on the Spider-Man property.

Comment: Also, how do they fit into the timeline? I'm prepared to ask another question on it